# Firebase realtime download 300kb+ for simple query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use a simple query to load data from firebase to viewpager using query I don't know why but just for 18 nodes it downloads 300+ kb,

whereas one node contains 6 values in it (post_id,posturl,date_created...)

```
query = db.orderByChild("random_no").startAt(min).endAt(max).limitToFirst(limit);

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Photo> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Photo>()
                    .setQuery(query, Photo.class)
                    .build();

    adapter=new videoadapter(options, getContext());
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

any idea what's I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `random_no` at `db` in your database rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, but know i understand that if you don't define .indexon then firebase download the whole nodes and query in cloud side

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question is simple that if you didn't define . indexon in your db rules then firebase download whole nodes to the client side and then query it which will cost you allot in long run.

So must define indexon rule to the db rule before commercial production of your app.

Learn more about Firebase .indexon -

[Firebase .indexon](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)